# Display data in TableWidget Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qtablewidget, filtered

```
{import os
import sys
import pyodbc as odbc
import pandas as pd
from check import * # check is my ui file

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(850,600)
        self.show()
        self.ui.locBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display())
        
    def display(self):
        DRIVER_NAME='SQL Server'
        SERVER_NAME='DESKTOP-TF6BQMV\SQLEXPRESS01'
        DATABASE_NAME='SCM'
        connection_string= f"""
        DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};
        SERVER={SERVER_NAME};
        DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};
        Trust_Connection=yes;
        """
        conn=odbc.connect(connection_string)
        c=conn.cursor()
        df=pd.read_sql("select * from TK",conn)
        tenTK=self.ui.tenTK.text()
        ltk=self.ui.tkCb.currentText()
        df=df[df["LoaiTK"]==0]
        self.ui.tbTK.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in df.iterrows():
            self.ui.tbTK.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.ui.tbTK.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
## EXECUTE APP
########################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())}
```

if I change to code: df=df[df["LoaiTK"]==1] tablewidget display my data, but if i keep code: df=df[df["LoaiTK"]==0] tablewidget display nothing. My database has 2 rows LoaiTK =1 and 0.

Comment: Nobody can help you with absolutely no context about the data structure nor how the function is called. Provide a [mre] (please, read that link *very carefully*) and as ***text***, not images!

Comment: i just edited, can you help me please. I have tried it many days.

Comment: It's probably caused by the fact that the resulting row number skip some rows when filtering (print the `row_number` and you'll see): for instance, if the table is empty (no rows) and the first result gives row number 1, `insertRow(1)` will do nothing, since you can only insert rows between 0 and the total row count, and any other value is ignored. Do `self.ui.tbTK.setRowCount(len(df))` before the loop, change to `for row_number, (_, row_data) in enumerate(df.iterrows())`:` and remove the `insertRow()` line. Note that the same should also be done for the column count and index for consistency.

Comment: Thank you so much @musicamante, you help me solve the problem that I have struggled for days.